# Pandas: run length of NaN holes

Tags: python, pandas

I have hundreds of timeseries objects with 100000's of entries in each.
Some percentage of the data entries are missing (NaN).
It is important to my application whether those are single, scattered NaNs or long sequences of NaNs.

Therefore I would like a function for giving me the runlength of each contiguous sequence of NaN.
I can do

```
myseries.isnull()
```

to get a series of bool. And I can do moving median or moving average to get an idea about the size of the data holes.
However, it would be nice if there was an *efficient* way of getting a list of hole lenghts for a series.

I.e., it would be nice to have a `myfunc` so that

```
a = pdSeries([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan])
myfunc(a.isnull())
==> Series([1, 3, 2])
```

(because there are 1, 3 and 2 NaNs, respectively)

From that, I can make histograms of hole lengths, and of the `and` or `or` of isnull of multiple series (that might be substitutes for eachother), and other nice things.

I would also like to get ideas of other ways to quantify the "clumpiness" of the data holes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan])
len_holes = [len(list(g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(a, lambda x: np.isnan(x)) if k]
print len_holes
```

results in

```
[1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: `Series([len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a.isnull()) if k])` is probably slightly more efficient.

Comment: Ah yes, 'groupby'.
I guess groupby is meant to operate on sorted data, but when not sorting first, it gets me exactly the RLE :)

Comment: Thanks, JAB, I didn't know groupby could take just a single parameter. That's great, because I have a.isnull() already calculated in my code

Comment: @JAB +1 for elegance, and also for efficiency: I got a 5x speedup using your method (3.65ms vs 15.9ms).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the runlength function from more_itertools:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import more_itertools as mit

a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan])
len_holes = [v[1]  for v in mit.run_length.encode(np.isnan(a)) if v[0]]
print (len_holes)
```