# Python conciseness confuses me

Tags: python

I have been looking at [Pandas: run length of NaN holes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16857407/2565842), and this code fragment from the comments in particular:

```
Series([len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a.isnull()) if k])
```

As a python newbie, I am very impressed by the conciseness but not sure how to read this. Is it short for something along the lines of

```
myList = []
for k, g in groupby(a.isnull()) :
    if k:
        myList.append(len(list(g)))
Series(myList)
```

In order to understand what is going on I was trying to play around with it but get an error:

```
list object is not callable
```

so not much luck there.

It would be lovely if someone could shed some light on this.

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: So the first snippet works while the second doesn't?

Comment: You just need to learn about Python comprehensions... list comprehensions, set comprehensions, etc.

Comment: `a` is not a normal list it is a `pandas.Series` other than that your interpretation is correct

Comment: Thanks everyone. To clarify, it's the first code snippet that's giving me the error...

Answer (score 5):

You've got the translation correct. However, the code you give cannot be run because `a` is a free variable.

My guess is that you are getting the error because you have assigned a list object to the name `list`. Don't do that, because `list` is a global name for the type of a list.

Also, in future please always provide a full stack trace, not just one part of it. Please also provide sufficient code that *at least* there are no free variables.

Comment: @arshajii How do you figure? Try `[]()`.

Comment: Apologies Marcin, I didn't want to repost the code from the original question, that's why I only cut out the snippet that was giving me a headache. You can see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16857854/2565842 for the whole code, it's just a couple of lines...

Answer (score 1):

If that is all of your code, then you have only a few possibilities:

1. `myList.append` is really a list
2. `len` is really a list
3. `list` is really a list
4. `isnull` is really a list
5. `groupby` is really a list
6. `Series` is really a list
7. The error exists somewhere behind `groupby`.

I'm going to go ahead and strike out `myList.append` (because that is impossible unless you are using your own `groupby` function for some reason) and `Series`. Unless you are importing `Series` from somewhere strange, or you are re-assigning the variable, we know `Series` can't be a list. A similar argument can be made for `a.isnull`.

So that leaves us with two real possibilities. Either you have re-assigned something somewhere in your script to be a list where it shouldn't be, or the error is behind `groupby`.

I think you're using the wrong `groupby` `itertools.groupby` takes and array or list as an argument, [`groupby` in `pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) may evaluate the first argument as a function. I especially think this because [`isnull()` returns an array-like object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html).